# How can I share PHP session between two android apps?

Tags: php, android

I am using xampp to send downstream and upstream messages between two android apps. In my php server I am successfully sending data to test1.php and test2.php. But I would like to share the values in some variables in both php files. It turns out the session id is unique with each interaction, thus impossible to access the variables from the second app. test1.php looks like:

```
<?php 
        //session 
        session_start();

        $json = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $jsondecoded = json_decode($json, TRUE);
        $Id = $jsondecoded['ID'];  

        $_SESSION['id'] = $Id;
?>
```

and test2.php looks like this:

```
<?php 
        //session
        session_start(); 

        $myid=$_SESSION['id'];
?>
```

But I get id undefined error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: well this variable isnt defined anywhere, -- if you store your data in reference to a user login, you can call all the data from the database in order to share session data or you can use an ajax call

Comment: Are test1 and test2 accessed by the same person? Or is this on different devices?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard they are on different devices by two different people.

Comment: Session data cannot be shared between two users like that. You'll have to use a database to make the variables available to both.

Comment: PHPSESSID http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Comment: thats my answer Jay...anyway, you could use a get variable ID, Quantum, to reference the table for the saved data ?id=1  for example, will pull the row from the table